# Pricing is unclear for bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

It is not clear to me how the payment works.

It says that after my trial account I have "paid usage". But I never see anything happen on my creditcard.

There's also an organisation involved, but I do not make costs there, it is purely about my own "organization" (personal account).

Then there's the 0.25 cents of support, and the runtime costs of a simple app.

I certainly hope it is not an annual payment cycle, because as of now I'm guessing that even though it says "paid usage", I still did not pay yet, and it is still probably some free tier. Is that correct?

See for example the image below; it seems to be clear that I have "credit card charge" (also for June), but I never got charged.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not relevant to this platform

Comment: How is this not relevant to the platform? How are costs ever not relevant to a platform? You could say that it does not fit the stackoverflow format, but with not open-source vendor (IBM) and other companies it is much more common to be able to deviate from the format on stackoverflow because this is a form of official support!

Comment: I'm sure there was even a post on it on meta stackoverflow, but I cannot find the link right now.

Comment: I mean the stackoverflow platform. I don't think pricing questions should be here, I not 100 % sure though so best of luck with the question.

Comment: @PaulWhelan I understand you, and I wouldn't have asked if it wasn't for that meta post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I believe this should be asked at SO meta. Or I don't see how this is related to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please address your issue to the following mail: billing@bluemix.net. They will help you specifically in this kind of problems. Some general information about charges and billing can also be found at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/acctmgmt/bill_usage.html